# Curly quotes implementation in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to implement curly quotes in XSLT. However, it fails for some edge cases.
Consider the following input:

```
<p>"This is a "sample quote text" that needs to be checked"</p>
```

Now, I want to convert straight quotes to curly quotes. All the implementations I have seen online replaces straight quotes to alternate opening and closing curly quotes. However, this fails in special cases like this wherein the output needed is:

```
<p>“This is a “sample quote text” that needs to be checked”</p>
```

What I am trying to do is check if there is a space present before the quote. If space present, then opening quote, else closing quote. Exceptions are quotes in the beginning and the end of the line. I am not really sure how to check previous character when a quote is encountered, and also handle handle the beginning and end quote at the same time.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Are you using XSLT 1.0 or 2.0? -- Note also that quoted phrases may not always be surrounded by spaces (or spaces alone) - for example: *Who said "some quote"?*.

Comment: I am using XSLT 2.0.
And for the example that you shared, don't the same rules apply? i.e Who said "some quote"?. would turn into Who said “some quote”?. 
Because I had mentioned in the initial post that quotes in the begining and the end of the line would be opening and closing quotes respectively. Just not sure how to implement that.

Comment: Well, then you could use the replace() function to replace space+quote with space+opening_quote and quote+space with closing_quote+space - although I suspect a smarter solution can be found using regex. -- No, the same rules do not apply to my example, because the second quote is not followed by a space, and it is not the last character of the string.

Comment: Oh. I am sorry, I missed that.
I was just thinking of tokenizing based on "space", if the text contains a quote. But your solution seems simpler. And faster to execute?
Such a simple solution, and I was breaking my head over it :/
Thanks a lot. I will implement this and get back :)

Answer (score 0):

I once faced a similar problem until I realized I was using XSLT to render HTML. Since I could use CSS, I finally came up with the solution below (source: http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/q/quotes/).

First, I define the CSS rules:

```
q {
  quotes: "“" "”" "“" "”";
}
q:before {
    content: open-quote;
}
q:after {
    content: close-quote;
}
```

As you can see, the `quotes` property in the CSS rule applied to `q` elements tells that the inner quotes in an already quoted text also use the same symbols.

Second, I used `<q>` instead of using " (I don't know if it's easy to do in your case; mine was).

Finally, the paragraph below is rendered as expected. Again, I'm assuming you are rendering HTML:

```
<p><q>This is a <q>sample quote text</q> that needs to be checked</q></p>
```

Comment: Both the input and output files are in XML format. I dont think CSS could help here. Is there a solution purely in XSLT?